# Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following CSP, Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, content-security-policy

We are trying to implement google analytics in our chrome extension. These are the steps we made:

Our `manifest.json` was edited to this:

```
"Content-Security-Policy": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'nonce-4AEemGb0xJptoIGFP3Nd'",
```

And our `index.html`:

```
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
    ga('create', 'XXXXX', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js' nonce="4AEemGb0xJptoIGFP3Nd"></script>

<!-- End Google Analytics -->
</head>
```

We tried using hash,nonce and unsafe inline but all gave this error code:

[image]

I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Google provides a [tutorial on adding GA to Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_analytics):

> #### Installing the tracking code
>
> The standard Google Analytics tracking code snippet fetches a file
>   named `ga.js` from an SSL protected URL if the current page was loaded
>   using the `https://` protocol. Chrome extensions and applications may
>   only use the SSL-protected version of `ga.js`. Loading `ga.js` over
>   insecure HTTP is disallowed by Chrome's default Content Security
>   Policy. This, plus the fact that Chrome extensions are hosted under
>   the `chrome-extension://` schema, requires a slight modification to the
>   usual tracking snippet to pull `ga.js` directly from
>   https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js instead of the default
>   location.
>
> Below is a modified snippet for the asynchronous tracking API (the
>   modified line is bolded):
>
> ```
> (function() {
>   var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
>   ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
>   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
> })();
> ```
>
> You'll also need to ensure that your extension has access to load the
>   resource by relaxing the default content security policy. The policy
>   definition in your manifest.json might look like:
>
> ```
> {
>   ...,
>   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> Here is a popup page (popup.html) which loads the asynchronous
>   tracking code via an external JavaScript file (popup.js) and tracks a
>   single page view:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>   <head>
>     ...
>     <script src="popup.js"></script>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     ...
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> ```
> var _gaq = _gaq || [];
> _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
> _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
>
> (function() {
>   var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
>   ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
>   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
> })();
> ```